# set target frame for onclick event

Tags: javascript

My onclick opens a page called index.html. My site has frames and I want to set the target frame. my function is in FRAME id="preview" and i want to load index.html in FRAME id="bu"

```
 onclick : function() {
            // Add you own code to execute something on click
          window.location = 'index.html';
        }
```

-

```
<FRAMESET id="frameset" rows="95,*" cols="*">
  <FRAME noresize="" id="tool" name="tool" src="Application/tool/<?=$id ?>">
  <FRAMESET COLS="81%,*">  
  <FRAME id="preview" name="preview" src="<?=$preview_url ?>"       onload="bu.setPreviewEvents()" >
  <frameset id="tcolor" rows="60,*" cols="*">  
    <FRAME id="colorfr" name="colorfr" scrolling="no" src="<?=$colorfr_url ?>" >
    <FRAME id="bu" name="bur" src="<?=$bu_url ?>" >
    </frameset>
  </FRAMESET> 
  </FRAMESET>
```

Comment: EEK framesets are deprecated in HTML5. Don't use them!

Comment: Woah, `frameset` - I didn't know frames were still in use anywhere :)

Comment: my friend, use <iframes> instead <frameset> and then edit the question, you will get an answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access the main window from any frame using [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.top). To refer a specific `frame` element, you can use its `name`, or [`frames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.frames) collection of the main window:

```
window.top.frames['bur'].location.href = 'index.html';
```

Notice, that `frames` collection contains the `window` objects within `frame` elements, not `frame` elements.